# Symfony + Docker, connection refused

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, docker

I'm seasoned in Symfony but quite new to docker, and I have a "connection refused error" I don't manage to solve.

Pretty sure it is a beginner error and that the solution here is quite simple...

Here is the content of my `docker-compose` file:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
    cg-demo:
        build: docker/cg-demo
        container_name: cg-demo
        working_dir: /var/www/html
        volumes:
            - .:/var/www/html
            - ./docker/demo/vhost.conf:/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:ro
            - ./docker/demo/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
            - ~/.ssh:/var/www/.ssh
            - ~/.composer:/var/www/.composer
        environment:
            - SYMFONY_ENV
            - DOMAIN_NAME: cg-demo.docker
            - VIRTUAL_HOST: cg-demo.docker
        depends_on:
            - database
        env_file: .env
        ports:
            - 8000:80

    database:
        image: percona:5.6
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        expose:
            - 3306
        container_name: cg-demo-database
        volumes:
            - /docker/database:/etc/mysql/conf.d
        environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
            MYSQL_DATABASE: demo
        tmpfs:
            - /var/lib/mysql
            - /tmpfs:size=300M
```

This has been based from another project that works, but I'm not sure of all that's happening here...

I also have a phpmyadmin container, not shown here. PhpMyAdmin connects correctly to the database and can use it without problem from any web server. However when it comes to the symfony container, I have this whenever trying to use the database:

```
[Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException]
An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused   

[Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

The connection information is the following, in a `.env` file:

```
# Database credentials
DATABASE_HOST=database
DATABASE_PORT=3306
DATABASE_USER=root
DATABASE_PASSWORD=root
DATABASE_DB=cg-demo
```

Calling `docker ps` gives me this:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND               
CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                  NAMES
16a67dadeebb        phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin "/run.sh phpmyadmin"     15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes             0.0.0.0:8001->80/tcp   cg.phpmyadmin.docker
8bd783aa1dd1        cg_cg-demo            "entrypoint.sh apa..."   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes             0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   cg-demo
2fc7cd9105ba        percona:5.6           "docker-entrypoint..."   15 minutes ago      Up 15 minutes (healthy)   3306/tcp               cg-database
```

I've tried to `ping database` from the demo container and it works...

**EDIT 1:**

Added the following to the database container:

```
ports:
    - 3306:3306
```

**EDIT 2:**

Removed the following from all containers:

```
networks:
    - default
```

**EDIT 3:**

My doctrine configuration in `app/config/config.yml`:

```
dbal:
    host:     "%env(DATABASE_HOST)%"
    port:     "%env(DATABASE_PORT)%"
    dbname:   "%env(DATABASE_DB)%"
    user:     "%env(DATABASE_USER)%"
    password: "%env(DATABASE_PASSWORD)%"
    charset: UTF8
    mapping_types:
        enum: string
    server_version: 5.6
```

**EDIT 4:**

Added the following to the database configuration:

```
expose:
    - 3306
```

Comment: you have to expose the port for mysql like you did with `cg-demo` service

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The post was updated (still doesn't work though)

Comment: One more thing, I had a similar issue, and I removed the `networks` attribute from the services and it worked

Comment: Did so, doesn't change anything

Comment: Can you show you `parameters.yml` file?

Comment: @ŁukaszD.Tulikowski That would not help a lot, since I use env vars instead of data in `parameters.yml`. I put you the relevant section of `config.yml` instead

Comment: Hi @zephyr, I'm having the same issue here. Did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: Hey, guys. I just posted a solution have a look. Wish I 'm helpful.

Comment: Could you @Zephyr Werlich please accept my answer if you think it solved your problem or was the most helpful in finding your solution. Thank you. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is for docker-compose version 2 and it also works on version 3:

The problem is a **Linking Containers** problem. We need to  define additional aliases that services can use to reach one another.

Expose **3306 port** will not solve your problem. **mysql or percona** container will expose by deffault that port. Take a look to the docker hub of [percona image.](https://hub.docker.com/_/percona/)
. It's mentioned there:

> Connect to MySQL from an application in another Docker container
>
> This image exposes the standard MySQL port (3306), so container
>   linking makes the MySQL instance available to other application
>   containers. Start your application container like this in order to
>   link it to the MySQL container:

```
$ docker run --name some-app --link some-percona:mysql -d application-that-uses-mysql
```

So, you should links the *database* to you *cg-demo* container. There's tow solutions:

1) Add a link under configuration :

```
services:
    cg-demo:
        build: docker/cg-demo
        container_name: cg-demo
    .
    .
    .
    links:
    - mysql
```

The diffirence between **depeds_on** and **links** is that `depends_on` `docker-compose up` will start services in dependency order. In your following example, `database` will be started before web.
We can also access data. But this is not enough, because we want to make sure that your web container (cg-demo) always connect to the database container.
**Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service.**
In the following example, database is reachable from web (`cg-demo`) at the hostname database. This means that the`cg-demo` can connect the database contanier from the 3306 port.

2) The second solution, is to configure the default network instead of (or in addition to) **customizing your own network**. Simply define a default entry under networks:

```
networks:
  bridge_name:
    driver: bridge
```

And then you should link every container to that bridge via `networks` tag:

```
cg-demo:
  .
  .
  networks:
    - bridge_name

database:
  .
  .
  networks:
    - bridge_name
```

Comment: Sorry, this was an old problem now, solved for me and I don't really recall how. I'll accept your answer - since no other one showed up.

Comment: Thank you maybe this gonna help someone else :)

Comment: here is the solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/54524887/2203384