# Symfony 4 "Connection refused" while trying to connect to docker mysql container

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

My question is how to configure connection to mysql container.

Here is my **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
php:
    build: ./php-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./iym:/var/www/iym
        - ./php-fpm/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    depends_on:
        - mysql
web:
    build: ./nginx
    ports:
        - "8888:80"
    volumes:
        - ./iym:/var/www/iym
        - ./nginx/iym.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    depends_on:
        - php
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6
    restart: always
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
        - ${DB_PATH_HOST}:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "symf0ny"
    ports:
        - "3306:3306"
```

And here is my DATABASE_URL in **.env** file

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:symf0ny@127.0.0.1:3306/iym
```

When i try to run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` i get an error like "`SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`". OS - ubuntu 18.04. What should i do to connect to DB? Many thanks!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your config files, not images.

Comment: Ok. I've just updated my post.

Comment: Can you post your whole docker-compose.yml? And where does you PHP run, in another docker-compose service?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

*I assume you are trying to connect from another container/service defined in docker-compose and you are using current version of docker-compose (2.4 or 3.7)*

You need to change

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:symf0ny@127.0.0.1:3306/iym
```

to

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:symf0ny@mysql:3306/iym
```

The reason is that `127.0.0.1` is refering to the localhost of the machine on which php runs. In this case it's the php's container localhost. But the db doesn't run there. It runs in another docker container, which can be reached under the service name, `mysql` in this case.

---

In [docker-compose networking docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) is written:

> By default Compose sets up a single network for your app. Each container for a service joins the default network and is both reachable by other containers on that network, and discoverable by them at a hostname identical to the container name.

but, the service is discoverable under the container name (which is automatically generated to `projectName_serviceName_1` (project name begin by default folder name), but also under service name, [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links) and [service alias](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#aliases) if defined. I would recommend using service name wherever possible.

More in docs: https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the Docker variable overrides the parameter from .env file and I'm trying to connect to the wrong host. Found that via `dd($this->constructPdoDsn($params))` in the `Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDO\MySQL\Driver::connect`, maybe it will be helpful